# Mac homebrew 'sqlite3' not found

Tags: sqlite, homebrew

I'm trying to compile `glyr` (for getting lyrics) from its source:

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr .
```

This ends on error

```
-- checking for module 'sqlite3'
--   package 'sqlite3' not found
```

But I have already installed sqlite3 via homebrew, if I give

```
$ brew install sqlite3
Warning: sqlite-3.8.2 already installed
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [their compile instructions](https://github.com/sahib/glyr/wiki/Compiling)

> Mac OS X
>
> The instructions for Linux are almost the same, but a few more steps may be needed:
>
> libintl is needed, install it from here https://code.google.com/p/rudix/downloads/detail?>name=static-libintl-0.18.1.1-5.pkg
>   You may need to link sqlite3.pc to /usr/local/pkgconfig/ with $ brew link --force sqlite
>   Details: https://github.com/sahib/glyr/issues/34